# rake assets:precompile throws Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "*/"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, compilation, precompile

*I hope this isn't a duplicate problem; I've tried other solutions on SO with no effect*

When pushing my app to Heroku, the push has failed because application.css has not been able to compile.

My terminal output:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " */": expected selector, was "@font-face"
(in /tmp/build_17e92975-ae8d-446f-8678-110eeeccfb64/app/assets/stylesheets/adminsite/application.css)
(sass):1845
```

**Attempts at solution**

I've searched and deleted every instance of "*/" that comes before an @font-face inside the ../stylesheets/adminsite/ directory. Same issue and result.

I've tried setting:

```
  config.assets.compile = true
```

...Same issue

**Edit**

Here is my application.css (not the app level one, but the one failing in the adminsite directory)

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require_self
 *= require normalize
 *= require ./global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap
 *= require ./global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default
 *= require ./global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch
 *= require ./global/css/components
 *= require ./global/css/plugins
 *= require ./global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons
 *= require ./admin/layout/css/layout
 *= require ./admin/layout/css/themes/light2
 *= require ./admin/layout/css/custom
 */
```

By removing and recompliling, I found that

```
*= require ./global/plugins/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome
```

that was 3 from the bottom of that list, was causing it to fail. I can now locally run

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

but I can't push to heroku using

```
git push herokunb newbeta:master
```

**SOLVED:**

It was the font awesome CSS. Removing that from require fixed it. The issue appeared unsolved only due to my own mistakes with git.

Comment: It's a file in a temp directory, not your project directory. Delete the file and try again. If it still complains, open the file and post the contents around line 1845 (or wherever it complains).

Comment: Can you post your application.css?

Comment: posted application.css. There is no "/tmp/build_17e92975-ae8d-446f-8678-110eeeccfb64/" ... seems to be constructed and deleted when using rake?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: If you remove your font awesome CSS, you can deploy your app successfully. But all your pages won't have that CSS. How do you deal with it?

Comment: checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73564234/445908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The file that was breaking things was the font awesome CSS. Removing that from application.css's "require" lines allowed the precompilation to work.

The way to do this was to first delete all of the precompilation require fields, showing that it would compile, and then to slowly add the require fields back to see where it broke.

(Thanks for all those who helped figure this out.)

Answer (score 14):

Even though you found your way to fix it, I'm gonna share my solution too, because I was facing the same issue and it was kinda hard to debug it.

You're probably using `rails` 3.2, `sass-rails` 3.2 and `font-awesome-sass` 4.1.

It turns out that the `rails` *3.2* uses `sass-rails` *3.2.6*, which depends on `sass` >= *3.1*. However, It looks like `sass` 3.1 is not compatible with `font-awesome` *4.1*, so I explicitely set the `sass` gem to use version 3.2 on my **Gemfile**.

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.6'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.2.0'
```

Hope this helps someone! ;)

Comment: I had the same problem, different versions, after the underlying `sass` gem was updated from 3.3.10 to 3.4.9. Setting it explicitly in the Gemfile fixed it: `gem 'sass', '~> 3.3.10'`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue as well and stumbled upon this thread.  Turned out for me, I left a } off of the end of one of my CSS statements.  Added it in and I was back up within minutes.

Comment: Very similar. I threw all my css files through the W3 css validator and it spotted an errant "

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to explicitly tell the asset-pipeline to use the css version of the asset over the scss one. For example, if you're importing a .scss file in your application.scss like this:

```
@import "angular-material";      # this will use scss version of the asset
```

You can alternatively tell it to use the css version like so:

```
@import "angular-material.css";  # this will use the css version
```

Most vendors provide scss and css versions, so it is useful to rely on css versions of assets especially when using vendor assets. Remember everything will be precompiled and uglified in the end, so wither you use scss or css they all end up the same.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I forgot to add # in front of the class sign-in.

It should be

```
#sign-in 
  (your code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie to rails and was having a similar issue when pushing to heroku. A friend looked at my application.css file and noticed that I had

`*= require bootstrap`

and

`*= require bootstrap-datetimepicker`

below the `*/`

Removing them allowed me to push successfully.