# Sass::SyntaxError at /. Invalid CSS after " }": expected "}", was ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

[image]My rails application was working fine the last time I ran it. Then restarted the server the other day to the error described on the title. This is by far the vaguest error message I have error received from a rails application.

Has anyone ever come across this? It does not state what file has the issue a page number, nothing. Just what I have included on the title.

I have done checks on my scss files and they do not have any errors. :(

Comment: I'm totally new to ruby etc, but maybe there has been an update to a [scss library that you include and that is incompatible with your specified scss version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25814412/3162554).

Comment: Hi @Marvin, thank you for the information above. I guess I had to just dig a little deeper. I had a scss file within a folder that was not well formed. I finally found it.