# SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "}":

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to precompile + minify my js and css assets.

If I run: `rake assets:precompile`

Then it runs fine, but doesn't minify.

If I run: `SECRET_KEY_BASE=`rake secret`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Then it returns an error message and doesn't compile: `SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was '!function(){if("und' on line 17881 of stdin`

I've tried updating various gems, changing some of the CSS, adding @import to application.scss, etc but none of it seems to be working.

Here's the full error message:

```
rake aborted!
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was '!function(){if("und'
        on line 17881 of stdin
>> }

   -^
stdin:17881
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sassc-2.0.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:49:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.0/lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb:29:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

What am I missing that will let it precompile and minify my js and css?

Comment: show the code, it complains about a CSS syntax error but the line shown on the error is Javascript

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for this, in the end I just deleted two instances in my CSS and JS that included the problematic line (`!function(){if(`).

Still not sure why they caused this error but as they were not actively used lines anyway (related to videos, which I don't currently use) I was happy enough to just delete and compile without them.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

to solve it, the key is find what is the content of "stdin", so we have to modify your local gem file and add debug outputs:

```
# edit (/home/siwei/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb)

   def call(*args)
     input = if defined?(data)
       data # sprockets 2.x
     else
       args[0][:data] #sprockets 3.x
     end
     # add these debug lines of code 
     puts "=== input is: "
     File.write('/tmp/temp_scss', input)
     puts "=== input end "

     SassC::Engine.new(
       input,
       {
         style: :compressed
       }
     ).render
   end
```

then run command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

then you will meet error, no worry, check out the file `/tmp/temp_scss`, find the "line 17881 of stdin", you will find the syntax error.

e.g. my error looks like:

[image]

just fix this bug and everything goes fine.