# Rails: SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "...ia screen\\0 and": expected "{", was "(min-width:769px) {"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, metronic

I have metroic theme installed on rails application when I try to compile assets I get issues.

```
rake aborted!
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "...ia screen\\0 and": expected "{", was "(min-width:769px) {"
        on line 17614 of stdin
>> @media screen\0 and (min-width:769px) {

   -------^
```

After debugging I found these issues are in following functions

```
@media screen\0 and (max-width:768px) {
    .m-grid.m-grid--ver-mobile.m-grid--mobile>.m-grid__item.m-grid__item--fluid,
    .m-grid.m-grid--ver-mobile.m-grid--mobile>.m-grid__item.m-grid__item--fluid-mobile {
        min-width: none
    }
}

@media screen\0 and (max-width:1024px) {
    .m-grid.m-grid--ver-tablet-and-mobile.m-grid--tablet-and-mobile>.m-grid__item.m-grid__item--fluid,
    .m-grid.m-grid--ver-tablet-and-mobile.m-grid--tablet-and-mobile>.m-grid__item.m-grid__item--fluid-tablet-and-mobile {
        min-width: none
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this function is unable to compile what is the issue?

Comment: It came from metronic theme, do you know what does that mean?

Comment: checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73564234/445908

Answer (score 1):

In my case with temporary solution:

i changed `application.scss` to `application.css`. It was worked as expect